# iOS scrolls to the top on input after first character

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, keyboard, scroll

Here's the scenario:

1. Open the website in Safari on an iPhone
2. Click/tap on an input text field
3. The window scrolls to vertically center the field in the viewport (fine)
4. Type the first character using the keyboard
5. iOS scrolls to the top of my page whereas I'd like it to stay as it was at step #3

I'm using jQuery, and tried a lot of different solution without success.

All I've learnt from this is that if I `preventDefault()` the event on `keydown` or `keypress` then it's not scrolling to the top, but there's no text in the input (obviously). When I try to do something like: `this.value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);` it scrolls up again.

I tried to cancel the `scroll` event without success as well.

Comment: have you tried using, this.value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); event.preventDefault(); both on the key press event.

Comment: @SHANK yes I did. I event tried to add `stopPropagation()`, `stopImmediatePropagation()` and `return false` on `keypress` with the value code.